# How can I parameterize an update using an "anonymous table"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm fairly sure that a big part of the reason I'm failing to find answers with Google is because I don't know the correct terminology to describe my problem.

I know the following form well:

```
UPDATE Table t
SET t.description = Concat(ot.text, ' text')
FROM Table
INNER JOIN Other_Table ot ON t.id = ot.id
WHERE conditions;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is more like:

```
UPDATE Table t
SET t.description = Concat(item, ' text')
FROM t
INNER JOIN (SELECT item FROM ('list', 'of', 'items'))
WHERE conditions;
```

In other words I have an "anonymous table", or a list of explicit strings specified in the query, rather than stored in a table, and I want them to be picked one at a time and concatenated with some string literal and to update a row.

So imagine I have a table of product information.  I want to update this table so the "description" column contains "This product is *color*!".  I'm looking for something like:

```
UPDATE Products p
SET p.desc = Concat('This product is ', color, '!')
FROM p
INNER JOIN (SELECT color FROM ('blue', 'red', 'green'))
WHERE p.sku in (111, 112, 113);
```

I'm using Access 2010 and connecting to a SQL Server 2008 DB.

Comment: Does 111 = blue, etc? If not, how do you decide on the colour? BTW Concat in MS Access is as simple as & : `[Field] & " Blue"`

Comment: Exactly why I needed help with this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 allows to use the VALUES clause as a table source:

```
CREATE TABLE products([desc] NVARCHAR(MAX),sku int)


UPDATE p
SET p.[desc] = 'This product is '+ C.color+ '!'
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN (VALUES(111,'blue'),(112, 'red'),(113, 'green')) AS c(sku,color)
ON p.sku = c.sku
WHERE p.sku in (111, 112, 113);
```

Comment: I like this one alot, thank you Sebastian.  Are the parenthesis correct in "Values(111,'blue'),(112,'red'),(113,'green')"?

Comment: I really hate `values` syntax, but this one looks nice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got you right, but try smth like this

```
update Products p set
    p.desc = Concat('This product is ', C.color, '!')
from p
    inner join
    (
        select 'blue' as color, 111 as id union all
        select 'red' as color, 112 as id union all
        select 'green' as color, 113 as id
    ) as C on C.id = p.sku
where p.sku in (111, 112, 113);
```

Comment: Not quite as compact as I'd hoped, but this looks like it will do what I'm asking.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, would it work if I did something like: inner join (select ('blue', 'red', 'green') as color, (111, 112, 113) as id)?

Comment: no, it will give you two rows with three columns (nvarchar I suppose) instead of three rows with two columns